# Not able to filter the required data

Tags: sql-server

Hi i have 1 table Student where data is inserted row wise and i want to select only those student whose marks are more than 50% in all the subjects and if in any subject marks are less than 50% then it should not select that student in output and all records should be excluded for that student and there is no primary key

i tried below code :

```sql
Select * into #temp1 from  Student  where percent >=0.5 and group by Roll_Number
```

i am getting error :

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

and if try like this :

```
Select * into #temp1 from  Student  where percent >=0.5
```

then i am getting students who has even in 1 subject more than 50% which is not required in output

Table structure is as follows

```
Student_Name   Roll_Number   Subject  Marks  Percent 
Ashutosh        1234         English  40     40% 
Ishan           1231         Maths    60     60% 
Atul            1232         Maths    30     30% 
Ashutosh        1234         MAths    70     70%
```

now in output it should only give

```
Ishan          1234        Maths     60     60%
```

Comment: Telling us what "is not required" does not help define what IS required. So - what are your requirements? You want to select all rows for those students that have a minimum "percent" value that is at least 0.5 for every row in that table? Or perhaps you want to base this on an average of all rows for a student? Using the average logic, Ashutosh would also be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count() over()` in order to indicate for every student if any row has < 50%, then use this as a filter criteria:

```
with s as (
    select *,
      Count(case when perc<0.5 then 1 end) over(partition by Student_Name) pc
    from Students
)
select *
from s
where Percent>=0.5 and pc=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result by using a subquery / cte and a window function in order to check if the student has at least 50% in all subjects:

```
DECLARE @Student TABLE(
Student_Name VARCHAR(20)
,Roll_Number int
,Subject VARCHAR(20)
,Marks int
,Perc DECIMAL(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Student VALUES
 ('Ashutosh',1234,'English',40,0.4)
,('Ishan',1231,'Maths',60,0.6)
,('Atul',1232,'Maths',30,0.3)
,('Ashutosh',1234,'Maths',70,0.7);

WITH cteFilter AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_Name, Roll_Number ORDER BY Perc ASC, Marks ASC) rn
    FROM @Student
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteFilter
  WHERE rn = 1
    AND Perc >= 0.5
```